# Dropdown Menu on Bootstrap 4 Navbar

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am having issues aligning a dropdown menu on the navbar-brand portion of the Bootstrap 4 Navbar. For some reason it is aligning to the top left of the page.

[image]

I have tried the following code below and am not sure how to go from there.

```
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
        <div class="container">


            <a class="navbar-brand dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              WebsiteName
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="/>WebsiteName</a>

              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <h6 class="dropdown-header">Popular Subdomains</h6>   
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/">Subdomain 2</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="/">Subdomain 3</a>                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="/">All Subdomains</a>
            </div>

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/two-link/">Two Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="/search">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just curiosity , are you tring to make your **brand** is dropdown cause its a big mistake try to read this docs to see how its work 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/navbar/
 you can also position your navbar by using float or flex alignment as you wish

Comment: Yes I want the brand part to be a dropdown. So you can switch to other websites (sub-domains) on the network quickly and easily.

Comment: is tht what you want ? , https://codepen.io/mhmdbrik/pen/LMeVYE  this issues that you remove id from your brand and give it to your .dropdown div and set href of your brand to that id ?